# Como fazer uma paginação que mostre somente Anterior - 6 registros - Proximo por página?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, bootstrap-4, paginação

```
<div id="paginadorMocado">
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
<ul class="pagination" id="paginacao">
<!--
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Anterior</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(1);">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(2);">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(3);">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(4);">4</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(5);">5</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(6);">6</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(7);">7</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(8);">8</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(9);">9</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(10);">10</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(11);">11</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(12);">12</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(13);">13</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(14);">14</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(15);">15</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="pagina(16);">16</a></li>                    
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Próx</a></li>
-->
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

if(cont === 0){
    
    var qtdPagina = parseInt(v0.qtderegistros / 20);

    var c = 1;

    $('#paginacao').html("");
    for (var i = 1; i <= qtdPagina; i++) {
        $('#paginacao').append("<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#' onclick='pagina("+i+");'>"+i+"</a></li>");                            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Tem paginas minhas que estão carregando mais de 100 paginções e não estou conseguindo resolver esse problema...

Comment: Uma dica! Utilizo esta biblioteca nos meus sites: https://packagist.org/packages/coffeecode/paginator . É do instrutor da Upinside, o Robson, muito fácil de usar. Dá uma olhada no final da paǵina de um dos meus sites em que utilizo o pacote: https://www.financecontrol.com.br/blog

Comment: Tem um jeito bem simples que sempre utilizo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOAJ2EQNtCk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o Jquery que desenvolveu pode fazer desta forma, ficaria a página atual, e mais 3 páginas anteriores e 3 posteriores:

```
var pagina = 5; //aqui você atribui a página atual, 5 é exemplo
var qtdPagina = parseInt(500 / 20); // coloquei 500 a fim de exemplo, mantenha seu código

var c = 1;
var ant = pagina - 1;


$('#paginacao').html("");

//inclui o botão anterior
$('#paginacao').append("</li><li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#' onclick='pagina("+ant+");'>Anterior</a></li>");

//loop em menos 3 até mais 3
for (var i = pagina - 3; i <= pagina + 3; i++) {
    $('#paginacao').append("<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#' onclick='pagina("+i+");'>"+i+"</a></li>");                            
}

var prox = pagina + 1;

$('#paginacao').append("</li><li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#' onclick='pagina("+prox+");'>Próx</a></li>");
```

Precisa desenvolver lógica pra verificar se é a última página, penúltima etc. Mas aí é um início.

Fidle do exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/75ax9g8r/

Comment: Valeu demais amigo, deu certo depois que desenvolver lógica pra verificar se é a última página ou a primeira para não aparecer -1.... : )